# Does Android has inbuilt config for Vertical Seekbar?

Tags: android, seekbar

Is there a reason why Android does not provide an inbuilt configuration for vertical seek bar? I had to used the code from http://560b.sakura.ne.jp/android/VerticalSlidebarExample.zip to make it work.

I read few threads on stackoverflow and they suggested as follows which obviously didn't work on my Samsung S4 and Droid Razr4:

```
<SeekBar
 android:id="@+id/seekBar1"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:rotation="270"/>
```

Am I missing something here? Please let me know your opinion.

Thanks
Raj

Answer (score 6):

> Does Android has inbuilt config for Vertical Seekbar?

No. For API 11+ you can use `android:rotation="270"`, as you've pointed out in your answer, and for earlier versions you'll need to look at open source implementations.

Here is another implementations I found, that may be useful for you:

https://github.com/AndroSelva/Vertical-SeekBar-Android

Here's what it looks like when using `android:rotation="270"`:

[image]

Comment: Hi Michell, I used android:rotation="270" for API 16 but it didn't work either.

Comment: The rotation API does work. It rotates the entire View. I've used it myself a few times before. I've just updated my answer with a screenshot showing what it looks like.

Comment: Hi Michell, after you replied I tried once again and this time I got the vertical seek bar to work but I am not able to make its height fill up the parent's height. My config:                <SeekBar
   android:id="@+id/SeekBar01"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:paddingTop="330dp"
   android:paddingBottom="0dp"
   android:paddingLeft="0dp" 
                 android:paddingRight="0dp"
                 android:minWidth="6dp"
                 android:maxWidth="600dp"  
   android:rotation="270"/>

Comment: Yeah, that's the real issue. It's not exactly easy to determine the size of the View when rotating it. Can't really help you with that.

Comment: 2 key notes:
1) the Vertical-Seek-Bar open source implementation does not have the same behavior as android's implementation. Notably, if you select the seek bar the selector does not change state, and if you disable the seek bar its behavior is quite different than if you rotate 270. 
2) It would also be helpful to emphasize in the answer that the width of the rotation gets translated into the height of the control, as described in these comments